# How to hide/show Collections levels with python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

how do we hide show a collection in blender 2.8

let say that this is the path to my collection

```
bpy.data.collections['SCATTER: [Plane.001] Particles']
```

[image]

Comment: The operator for that is `bpy.ops.outliner.item_openclose()`. Besides a custom context it also requires the cursor to be placed at the element that is toggled. I don't think this is practically possible for an add-on to do both because shifting the cursor with `bpy.context.window.cursor_warp()` would be very irritating to the user, but more importantly the x,y position of the collection in the outliner is unknown.

Comment: pfouah this is such a bad api implementation. this should be accessible right from data :(

Answer (score 2):

The operator that toggles the collection visibility in the outliner is [`bpy.ops.outliner.item_openclose()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.outliner.html#bpy.ops.outliner.item_openclose). Unfortunately it depends on the cursor position to determine the collection that should be toggled. While we could position the cursor with [`bpy.context.window.cursor_warp()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window.cursor_warp) the x and y coordinates of the collection in the UI remain unknown. It's therefore not realistically possible to perform this operation in a script or add-on.

I could get it to work with manually determined coordinates to position the cursor on the arrow icon in front of the collection.

```
import bpy


context = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                context['area'] = area
                context['region'] = region
                break
        break

# Places the cursor directly on the arrow icon for the first collection with
# my screen resolution and UI layout.
bpy.context.window.cursor_warp(2150,1250)
bpy.ops.outliner.item_openclose(context, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

 the problem is that this script wouldn't work if the user doesn't have an outliner open in his window.

Comment: It doesn't work in general, since you don't know the x,y coordinates since the UI layout and screen resolution are likely different. Perhaps there is a different way to approach this problem. Why do you want to toggle the collection in the outliner?

Comment: because i'm creating collections and some users are annoyed to close them manually each time, which i understand.

Comment: There are some options, however they aren't very selective and also require a custom context. `bpy.ops.outliner.show_one_level()` for expanding or collapsing one level or `bpy.ops.outliner.expanded_toggle()` to expand or collapse all elements.