# Programmatically collapse selected collection

Tags: python, collections, outliner

Related to [How to hide/show Collections levels with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140889/how-to-hide-show-collections-levels-with-python)

I'm writing an addon that generates nested collections. I would like to collapse its root collection.

[image]

Shift + Left arrow shortcut corresponds to  [`bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk(direction='LEFT', toggle_all=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.outliner.html#bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk). I've tried changing area type to Outliner and executing this operator, overriding context, but it all results in error:

**ERROR** (wm.operator): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.cc:1419 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OUTLINER_OT_select_walk'

```
class MY_OT_collapse_root_collection(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "my_addon.collapse_root_collection"
bl_label = "Collapse root collection"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
bl_description = ""

def execute(self, context):
    # area = context.area
    # area_type = area.type
    # area.type = 'OUTLINER'
    # bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk(direction='LEFT', toggle_all=True)
    # area.type = area_type
    # return {'FINISHED'}

    area_type = 'OUTLINER'
    areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]
    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        window=bpy.context.window,
        area=areas[0],
        regions=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
        screen=bpy.context.window.screen
    ):
        bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk(direction='LEFT', toggle_all=True)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```