# Use Outliner operators without Outliner context

Tags: python, scripting, operator, outliner

Looking for a way to use Outliner operators without mouse hovering over Outliner window.
So far got this code to simply walk select outside of Outliner window:

```
import bpy
class KEY_OutlinerWalckUp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.key_outlinerwalckup"
    bl_label = "KEY_OutlinerWalckUp"
    def execute(self, context):
        win = bpy.context.window
        scr = win.screen
        areas = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'OUTLINER']
        regions = [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
        
        with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, area=areas[0], region=regions[0], screen=scr):
            bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk()
        return {'FINISHED'}
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(KEY_OutlinerWalckUp)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KEY_OutlinerWalckUp)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And this error:

> ERROR (wm.operator):
> C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v360\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.cc:1550
> wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'OUTLINER_OT_select_walk'

I already know that blender got problems with outliner context. But maybe someone already provided a workaround to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! I think it's because the `bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk` operator is not directly usable in scripts in the same way as other operators. It's primarily designed for user interaction within the Outliner. So you will have to come up with another way to mimick this behavior, like taking note which item is selected and select the next item to it when the operator is invoked.

Comment: related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279271/programmatically-collapse-selected-collection

Comment: @blen_coders telegram channel helps with this code: `override = {"area": next(area for area in context.screen.areas if area.type == "OUTLINER")}
        bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk(override, "INVOKE_DEFAULT", direction="DOWN")`

Comment: take note that that is deprecated method of overriding and will not more be supported in version 4.0.

Comment: And what method shell we use in 4.0 ?

Comment: The explanation is in the first comment. You basically can't use `select_walk`. You have to find another way.